# What does $\varepsilon \leq 1 \wedge s$ mean?

Tags: notation, proof-explanation, rational-numbers

I'm reading Section. *The Rational Numbers* in textbook *Analysis I* by Amann/Escher. Below is Proposition 10.9:

> [image]

and part of its proof:

> [image]

From what the authors write, I guess that $\color{blue}{\varepsilon \leq 1 \wedge s}$ means $(\varepsilon \leq 1) \wedge (\varepsilon \leq s)$.

My questions:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Is that kind of notation common in mathematics community?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $\land$ symbol refers to the "[meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet)" of the two numbers. Given a partially ordered set, $x \land y$ refers to the greatest lower bound of $x$ and $y$. That is, it refers to an element $z$ such that $z \le x$ and $z \le y$, and given any $z' \le x$ and $z' \le y$, we also have $z' \le z$. Note that, in a partial order (in particular, if $x$ and $y$ are not comparable), such a point need not exist, and if it does, it need not be equal to $x$ or $y$ (it is, however, unique if it does exist).

In this case, we have a totally ordered set. Therefore, $x \land y$ refers to $\min \{x, y\}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, though the notation is that way for perhaps not the reason you expect. $a \wedge b$ is standard notation for what is called the *meet* of $a$ and $b$ and is equivalent to $\min(a,b)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet.